# UpUp to force the offline.html even when online

Tags: service-worker

So I am trying to use the UpUp library to build a offline first webpage.

The library shows the offline page when I am offline. How do i force UpUp to show the offline page irrespective of being online or offline.

What I am trying to do is build something like, the app shell will always be loaded from the service worker cache and the network calls be made from there. That would make my app load much faster as the initial page load won't be from the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not the author of [UpUp](https://github.com/TalAter/UpUp), but my understanding is that the library isn't intended to facilitate using the Application Shell model. Perhaps at some point it will evolve to fill that role, and you could always ask on the project's [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/TalAter/UpUp/issues).

In the meantime, there are a few resources out there describing how you can build applications following that model, either using the [`sw-precache`/`sw-toolbox`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/service-worker-libraries/) library combination, or writing your own service worker code:

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/11/app-shell
- https://speakerdeck.com/jeffposnick/instant-loading-with-service-workers-chrome-dev-summit-15
- http://www.pocketjavascript.com/blog/2015/11/23/introducing-pokedex-org